# matlab double title and xticks for xaxis label

Tags: matlab, plot

Am trying to plot a graph in Matlab, exactly like this image attached.

Now the problem is in the x axis label, and in the title. I know how to plot the image, the colorbar, the title of the colorbar etc..

but I can't figure out a way to modify the xlabel plot to look like the xlabel and xticks in the image as well as a text to say this is the latitude and this is the longitude as in  the bottom right of this image.

1-I have two arrays (each one of them is a 1D array (one is latitude and one is longitude)), so how can I force the XLABEL to plot the latitude values and the longitude values of these arrays in the xaxis of the image and add a text mentioning its latitude and longitude as I described above?

2- in the title, I also need to add the time on the top of the image as xaxis too, and how to add a title on the left top and the right top of the image that are a bit higher than the title of the image ?

[image]

```
`figure
imagesc (latitude, Altitude, myimage)
shading interp
axis xy
set(gca, 'xticklabel', [])
yTicks = get(gca,'ytick');
xTicks = get(gca, 'xtick');
minX = min(xTicks);
VerticalOffset = 0.1;
HorizontalOffset = 0.6;
for yy = 1:length(yTicks)

text(minX - HorizontalOffset, yTicks(yy) - VerticalOffset,     
['$$\begin{array}{c}', num2str( yTicks(yy)),'\\',num2str(         
 2*yTicks(yy)),'\end{array}$$'], 'Interpreter', 'latex')
end
minY = min(yTicks);
VerticalOffset = 0.6;
HorizontalOffset = 0.0;
 xxTicks=gps_lon;
str=strcat(num2str(xTicks(end)),[],'Latitude',[], '(degree North)');
str2=strcat(num2str(xxTicks(end)),'Longitude', '(degree East)');
for xx = 1:length(xTicks)
   if xx==length(xTicks)
      text(xTicks(xx) - HorizontalOffset, minY - VerticalOffset,    
      ['$$\begin{array}{c}', str,'\\', str2,'\end{array}$$'],   
       'Interpreter', 'latex')
  else
      text(xTicks(xx) - HorizontalOffset, minY - VerticalOffset, 
      ['$$\begin{array}{c}', num2str( xTicks(xx)),'\\',num2str( 
      xxTicks(xx)),'\end{array}$$'], 'Interpreter', 'latex')
  end

end

  ylabel('Altitude (km)', 'FontSize', 24);
  title('Time (UTC)', 'FontSize', 24);
  colormap('jet')
  mycolorbar=colorbar;
  LabelText='Title2 (unit)';
  ylabel(mycolorbar, LabelText)
  xtopTicks=time;
  axes
  set(gca,'xlim',[min(time) max(time)],'XAxisLocation','top')
  VerticalOffset = 0.0;
  HorizontalOffset = 0.0;
  for xx = 1:length(xTicks)
      text(xtopTicks(xx) - HorizontalOffset, minY - VerticalOffset, 
      ['$$\begin{array}{c}', num2str( xtopTicks(xx)),'\\','
       \end{array}$$'], 'Interpreter', 'latex')
  end`
```

Thanking you in advance for help

Comment: Can you upload what you can do already? Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867181/dividing-a-figure-and-handling-xticks-matlab?rq=1

Comment: this is very different from what I want to do, it is using the bar function or hist, and not imagesc or pcolor, it doesn't apply to what I want to do

Comment: Which version of Matlab? Look at [New line in axis tick labels in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34135766). That might give you some ideas.

Comment: I have uploaded the code am using, and the matlab version is R2014b

Comment: Am uploading what I managed to do based on kkuilla's link, but am having a problem putting a space between the numbers and the title on the bottom right. I also have the other problem which is to add xtick and xlabel on the top of the figure